# Keep hover-triggered twitter bootstrap popover alive while selecting option from a dropdown inside the popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, popover

I'm trying to put a dropdown list inside the twitter bootstrap popover. The popover should be triggered on link's hover event and remain visible while cursor is inside the popover.

I used a code posted by @vikas devde from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989591/how-can-i-keep-bootstrap-popover-alive-while-the-popover-is-being-hovered/17997192#17997192) to make it work, and everything works great except selecting an option from a dropdown list.

When trying to select an option, dropdown disappears.

In Firefox there is a chance to select by keyboard arrows, Chrome allows to select but hides the popover on click or on enter, in Safari everything works fine.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pavlopanasenko/rjrhqk40/32/) for illustration.

HTML:

```
<a id="hover-link" href="#">Hover over me</a>
<form id="form-popover" method="post">
    <label>Select some option here
        <select>
            <option>Option 1</option>
            <option>Option 2</option>
            <option>Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('#hover-link').popover({
                html: true,
                trigger: 'manual',
                placement: 'bottom',
                content: $('#form-popover').html(),
                title: "title"
            }).on("mouseenter", function () {
                var _this = this;
                $(this).popover("show");
                $(this).siblings(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(_this).popover('hide');
                    }, 100);
                });
            }).on("mouseleave", function () {
                var _this = this;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
                        $(_this).popover('hide');
                    }
                }, 100);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appeared to be a known issue with Firefox and Chrome firing parent's "mouseleave" event when opening a dropdown.
Just leaving it here for anybody having the same issue:

Thanks @Blocka and @gogobu for posting the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096843/funky-jquery-mouseleave-behavior).

I've added `e.target.tagName != 'OPTION'` and `e.target.tagName != 'FORM'` conditions to original code because `<form>` and `<option>` elements fired "mouseleave" event too.

In my case the complete solution looks like this:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pavlopanasenko/gursgv87/3/)

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('#hover-link').popover({
        html: true,
        trigger: 'manual',
        placement: 'bottom',
        content: $('#form-popover').html(),
        title: "title"
    }).on("mouseenter", function () {
        var _this = this;
        $(this).popover("show");
        $(this).siblings(".popover").on("mouseleave", function (e) {
            // e.fromElement and e.target.tagName hack to manage firing .popover "mouseleave" event when dropdown is open on Firefox and Chrome
            if ((typeof e.fromElement != 'undefined' && !e.fromElement.length) || (typeof e.fromElement == 'undefined' && e.target.tagName != 'SELECT' && e.target.tagName != 'OPTION' && e.target.tagName != 'FORM')) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(_this).popover('hide');
                }, 100);
            }
        });
    }).on("mouseleave", function () {
        var _this = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
                $(_this).popover('hide');
            }
        }, 100);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(function () {
    $('#hover-link').popover({
                html: true,
                trigger: 'manual',
                placement: 'bottom',
                content: $('#form-popover').html(),
                title: "title"
            }).on("mouseenter", function () {
                var _this = this;
                $(this).popover("show");
                $(this).siblings(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(_this).popover('active');
                    }, 100);
                });
            }).on("mouseleave", function () {
                var _this = this;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
                        $(_this).popover('hide');
                    }
                }, 100);
    });
});
```

this is where the problem is  `$(_this).popover('hide');` .. You need to make it active if you dont want it to hide so by replacing hide into active.. your hover buttons will be active

Comment: The problem is clearly in `$(_this).popover('hide')` but if I change 'hide' to 'active' the popover won't close on mouseleave as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Firefox allows the click event to propagate through to the popover causing the popover to dismiss. So, perhaps this is a simpler, more straightforward approach, since "active" is not a documented function for Bootstrap popovers.

```
$(document).on('click','select.popover-specific-select-element',function(event){
    // Hack to make sure the popover stays open when using Firefox.
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```